# How to find the directory of VSCode after snap installation

Tags: command-line, snap, visual-studio-code

I've installed VSCode using `sudo snap install --classic code` but when I search for "Visual Studio Code" or "vscode" on the GUI search, nothing pops up. How can I find the directory the snap is installed to using terminal? Also how can I see the full directory path using GUI? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try on one the devices listed by
`$ lsblk -ap | grep -E 'NAME|loop' --color=none`

... check the mounted ones first (cannot provide examples, snap uninstalled!)

*Due to issues similar to this, I prefer installing via ppa or .deb only.*

*Note also:*
`$ which code`
...should (in theory at least) show you the path of the executable.
`$ type -a code`
... might also reveal something.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe VSCode is not installed because my VSCode shows up in the Dash when I type `vs` , but if it is installed you can also start it from the terminal by running `code` (the name of the VSCode snap package).